# Software for motion analysis of video

Tags: video

Is there a software that can take a video and trace motion to produce a map of frequently trafficked areas? I work in a factory that has IP cameras placed throughout the facility and I am investigating methods for motion studies. Thanks.

Comment: You need some post processing software for combining motion blur and ghosting, I've seen some awesome video that tracks birds movement in some city and if I find the video I'll link it to you.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there was already a utility for the application but the best I could find is the OpenCV library.